# I just created a snipe command for my bot but it doesn't quite work

Tags: node.js, discord.js

My messageDelete event handler:

```
client.on("messageDelete", message => {
snipe.set(message.channel.id, {
title: Date.now(),
content: message.content,
author: message.author,
image: message.attachments.first() ? message.attachments.first().proxyURL : null,
});
});
```

My snipe.js code:

```
require('discord-reply');
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const moment = require('moment')

module.exports = {
    name: 'snipe',
    aliases: [],
    category: 'Fun',
    utilisation: '{prefix}snipe',
    description: 'Displays the last deleted message in the current channel!',
    execute(client, message) {
    
    const snipe = require('.././../index.js')
    const msg = snipe.get(message.channel.id);
    const timeAgo = moment(msg.title).fromNow();
            if (!msg) return message.channel.send("Theres Nothing To Snipe here...");
            if (msg.image) {
                const embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(msg.author.tag, msg.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                    .setTitle(`Message deleted by ${msg.author.tag}! (${timeAgo})`)
                    .setDescription(msg.content)
                    .setColor(0x3498DB)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setImage(msg.image)
                    .setFooter("Sniped by " + message.author.tag);
                message.lineReply(embed1);
            }
            else {
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(msg.author.tag, msg.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                    .setTitle(`Message deleted by ${msg.author.tag}! (${timeAgo})`)
                    .setDescription(msg.content)
                    .setColor(0x3498DB)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFooter("Sniped by " + message.author.tag);
                message.lineReply(embed);
            }
},
}
```

I am getting the following error in my console when I try running the command

```
(node:6928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: snipe.get is not a function
```

Can anyone help? I'm pretty sure my code is correct as I used the same thing in my old bot. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is in `'.././../index.js'`? That path seems weird (see the one single `.` in there?)

Comment: '.././../index.js' is where I've added the messageDelete event, you mean to tell me I need to use a single '.' ? Aight Imma try it. Edit: I double checked the path and everything is correct.

Comment: No, I don't mean that. Are you sure you mean `.././../index.js`, which is equal to `../../index.js`? Did you maybe mean `../../../index.js`?

Comment: yeah I want to use my main index.js file

Comment: Lemme try your path once

Comment: Why would your "main index.js file", whatever it is, have a `.set` and `.get`?

Comment: Maybe snipe is a map, you need to export it using either `module.exports` or binding it to your client

Comment: Well, it needs to set the snipe and later get that when I run the command

Comment: Lemme try exporting snipes

Comment: I still get the same error...

Answer (score 1):

From what I assume your `snipe` is a `Map`/`Collection` since you are using `get/set` on it, you may want to export the map to use it in your command file by binding it to your client like so

```js
const snipe = new Map();
```

Aliter

```js
const { Client, Collection } = require("discord.js");
const snipe = new Collection()
const client = new Client();
// Binding to Client
client.snipe = snipe // aliter declare it directly as client.snipe = new Collection()
```

Then you may access your collection since you are already exporting client like so

```js
client.snipe.set()
client.snipe.get()
```

Comment: Hey, when I added the module.exports function I forgot to add the import function in my snipe.js file. As soon as I did so, my code started working again. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment:  no issues but you can't use `import` without  `ES6/ ECMA6`, unless you're on Typescript... I wonder what youre talking about lol maybe you specified the filepath wrong?